# Returning an HTML/XHTML file from servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, xhtml

I've seen servlets examples, they're something like this:

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">");
        ...
    }
```

My question is, instead of the code, can I return an HTML page? I mean, something like this:

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            SHOW(FILE.HTML);

        }
```

Thanks!!! ;)

Comment: Do you want static html or dynamic html from a jsp?

Comment: You need to use a `RequestDispatcher` and forward the request. Search around on the site for `servlet forward to jsp` or look on our servlet wiki page.

Comment: It seems that you're new to servlets in general. I recommend to check out our servlets tag wiki page. Put your mouse on top of `[servlets]` tag which you put on the question until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link. Other tags (may) have similar wiki pages.

Comment: By the way, returning a XHTML file plain vanilla makes no utter sense.  It has no value for webbrowsers. Just make it a HTML file. But that's a different subject.

Comment: @BalusC I've started with jsf 2 weeks ago, with webServices 2 days ago and yesterday with servlets. You can laugh at me all you want ;)

Comment: I just pointed out a misconception so that you can learn from it. You learn nothing from being laughed at.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could do this:

1. Forward the servlet to the path where the HTML file is located. Something like:

   `RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("something.html");
   rd.forward(request, response);`
2. Send a redirect to the URL where the HTML is located. Something like:

   `response.sendRedirect("something.html");`
3. Read in the contents of the HTML file and then write out the contents of the HTML file to the servlet's PrintWriter.